# Webpack configuration for react app to include source maps from other react packages listed as dependencies

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

What changes need to be made to the webpack.config.js generated by a default react app so that you can debug *.jsx files from other react packages listed as dependencies ? The idea is to make use of the source maps delivered by dependencies so that you can debug Jsx code and not transpiled js.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for this:
https://github.com/webpack-contrib/source-map-loader

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: ["source-map-loader"],
        enforce: "pre"
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Include your loader, I used before to include dependencies on my source map

Comment: it doesn't work for a react app, I tried this already into webpack.config.js for default react app config

Comment: @BogdanZz do you eject and include the rule? which version of CRA do you have?